# Getting the Value of the Query to Populate Form Fields

Tags: coldfusion

I had a Query Where i am Getting 14 records and i need to Populate this records in 4 form fields, they are coming as

```
select id, name, value from mytable
```

check the attached Screenshot.

[image: How Records are appearing]

I cannot do cfoutput query as it will loop the form fields 14 times,

i tried something like

*queryname.name[currentow]*, but it not worked, checked this URL of cflib http://cflib.org/udf/queryGetRow

but that did not seems to get work. **need to populate the value of the name column in the form field**

need to know what is the right way

Comment: If you are getting 14 records and only want one, which one do you want?

Comment: i want to fetch all fourteen but as my the image, i need to put the value of the query who name is name:value pair like ace: hello {name}, need to put that hello {name} in the textarea, i am thinking of using evaluate but not sure that will server the purpose

Comment: If you only need one record, you should only be retrieving one record...not 14. You need to rethink your process here.

Comment: If you want all 14 records, you need a set of form fields for all 14.  If you want less than 14 sets of form fields, then you want fewer than 14 records and you need to know which ones you want.  If you think you want fewer than 14 sets of form fields, but 14 records, ask yourself why.  Don't attempt to code anything until you have an answer that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I did it, Here is if someone encounters this, i may not be able to correctly tell what is required. So here is my Solution:

```
<cfset rsSettings= initial.getSettings()>
<cfloop array="#rsSettings#" index="k">
    <cfset settings[k['name']] = k['value']>
</cfloop>
```

My Query is returning me an array, Using ben's post

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/124-Ask-Ben-Converting-a-Query-to-an-Array.htm

so to fill the form i used like this and it worked

```
<input type="text" name="pri" class="text" value="<cfoutput>#settings['pri']#</cfoutput>" />
```

if you guys have better solution, please share

Comment: So.. you needed all 14 record or not?  I am confused... All you did was take the records and put them into an array. Then on top of that each loop of the array overwrote the last.  So you really didn't do anything but write extra code that is unnecessary.

Comment: so, provide me a best practice code which you can share, so i learn something new, and yes that all 14 fields being used, like tce: a,b,c, so tce has tree values associated to it, that comes in single form field

Comment: If you know which row you want, you typically select the pertinent info using a `where` clause in your SQL. e.g.: `select id, name, value from mytable where id = XXX` where XXX is the id of the row you want.

Comment: i think you are not getting it @phantom42

Comment: OK, then explain it better. You're returning 14 rows, but you only want one. This is how you do that.

Comment: honestl my friend, i think i got confused what to ask; I will try to explain again: Auume i have two columns in my table {name & Value}. It has four rows. Now i have to populate the form fields of the rows 1 to 4, which contains the the details from the value column of the table

Answer (score 1):

From this comment only,

"honestl my friend, i think i got confused what to ask; I will try to explain again: Auume i have two columns in my table {name & Value}. It has four rows. Now i have to populate the form fields of the rows 1 to 4, which contains the the details from the value column of the table"

I would do this to build my form:

```
<cfquery name="data" datasource="whatever">
select name, value
from mytable
</cfquery>

<form action="somewhere.cfm" method="post">
<cfoutput query="data">
<input name="name_#name# value="#value#">
</cfoutput>
</form>
```

Processing the form is outside the scope of the question so I won't do it.  However, I will mention some potential problems.  If name is a text field, and it's values contain spaces, puncuation marks, etc, your page will crash due to an invalid variable name.  If your table has an id field that is either uuid or numeric, that's a better field to use.

Comment: but @Dan, Tis way it will loop 14 times, which is not required, i have only few form fields and and based upon on the name parameter, i ppulate the value inside the value of the input value field from the query